# script printing after a click event

Tags: javascript, html, document.write

I am working a project and using JavaScript to print onto the HTML page. I want to be able to click the <**a**> then have the script get executed and print in the HTML. I have two separate JS files, one for the animation of the <**a**> I am using, the other to print the text onto the HTML. I have tried onclick="document.write('showFizzBuzz')) inside of the anchor tag but I get a violation error in localhost to not use onclick with document.write.  As of right now it is just printing my script underneath my footer. Any suggestions please?

Below is both of my JS files

```
$(function() {
    $('.btn-6')
        .on('mouseenter', function(e) {
            var parentOffset = $(this).offset(),
                relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left,
                relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
            $(this).find('span').css({ top: relY, left: relX })
        })
        .on('mouseout', function(e) {
            var parentOffset = $(this).offset(),
                relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left,
                relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
            $(this).find('span').css({ top: relY, left: relX })
        });
    $('[href=#]').click(function() { return false });
});
```

```
var sum;
var i;

document.write("Results!", "<p>");

sum = 0;

for (let i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
        document.write("FizzBuzz", "<br>");
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
        document.write("Fizz", "<br>");
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
        document.write("Buzz", "<br>");
    } else {
        document.write(i, "<br>");
    }
}
```

and the HTML

```
    <div class="wrap">
      <a class="btn-6" href="#" onclick = "(document.write('showFizzBuzz'))">FizzBuzz<span>. 
      </span></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write()`, use DOM methods.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid ***inline-events*** as much as possible, and you should be using `.innerText()` method for `a`.

You should be doing it something like this-

```
document.querySelector('a.btn-6').addEventListener((e)=> {
  e.target.innerText = 'showFizzBuzz';
});
```

Comment: ```document.getElementById("innerTextOutput").onclick = function changeContent() { for (let i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {
        if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
            document.getElementById("innerTextOutput").innerHTML += ('FizzBuzz \n');
        } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
            document.getElementById("innerTextOutput").innerHTML += ('Fizz \n');
        } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
            document.getElementById("innerTextOutput").innerHTML += ('Buzz \n');
        } else {
            document.getElementById("innerTextOutput").innerHTML += (i + '\n');``` Thanks for the help

Comment: Comments should not be used for code snippets. Also, if you're using `innerTextOutput` node that many times, then it'd be better to just declare it once under `const innerTextOutput`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, going to try that out!